# Linux Kali on MS VirtualBox WIFI Not Working

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

So, I am new to using any type of linux OS.  The first place I decided to start was with a virtual machine (MS VirtualBox) and run Kali Linux.  The OS image downloaded perfectly, and so did MS VirtualBox.  I can even run the OS, but the main problem is that I cannot connect to my wifi.  There are not any error codes, it's just that when I go into the place where WIFI profiles should appear there is nothing there to connect to.  I also tried using an Ethernet cable to try to connect my laptop directly to my router.  But still nothing.  Is there a setting on VB I need to turn on?  Why is this problem caused, and how can I fix it?  Thanks.

Comment: 1) VirtualBox is not a Microsoft product, so it's unclear what you're actually using here; 2) it's not the usual practice to run your wifi inside a VM; 3) worth reading: [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me) (especially the various bold pieces of the answer).

Comment: @JeffSchaller It simply isn't a duplicate of that question.

Comment: I’m basing it on “I’m new to using any type of Linux OS”

Comment: @MichaelHomer But that's what that pseudo-question was made for.

Comment: @HaukeLaging It's certainly *used* in this way, yes; it fundamentally is not a legitimate duplicate of this question and would not provide any useful answer to the problem here. Voting to close as a duplicate is not a good-faith attempt to be helpful.

Comment: @MichaelHomer That depends on your understanding of helpful. In my understanding the attitude of the Kali pointer question is that telling those users not to use Kali at all is a big help for them. You may disagree on that but that does not put the others in bad faith.

Comment: In what way would using a different distribution resolve this issue? It wouldn't. Is this question actually about Kali in any way? No. The supposed duplicate clearly wouldn't resolve the issue in this question (obvious to anybody who ought to be voting on it). Suggesting it would is thus *not* a real attempt to address the problem; it's known that it won't help. We can all speculate on what people are actually getting from it when they VTC Kali-tagged questions as a duplicate of that one, but it's not relevant to whether it was actually a duplicate in that instance or not. VTC unclear, sure.

Comment: @MichaelHomer I admit that my attitude was like "If he doesn't even understand that then he should not use Kali" which I felt was the idea of the pointer question. But I can accept the argument that a Kali question should not be closed if the same problem would have appeared with normal distros. Nonetheless the asker should be pointed at the "Kali question".

Answer (score 1):

In a virtual box the guest system doesn't see the real hardware, and  typically the only network adapters in the guest are (emulated) Ethernet adapters. You should have such an adapter by default in Kali, that sees the Windows host as a router... Many tools in Kali require direct access to real network adapters and so are useless in a virtual machine. AFAIK there is a VirtualBox edition where the guest can see more real hardware, but this is a commercial product, and in any case that would require a careful setup to avoid impacting the network connection of the Windows host.

But if you just want to try Linux, there are plenty of simpler distributions.